# Magento 2 Add Custom Select to Customer : Source Model

Tags: magento2, module, customer, source-model

I added an attribute to customer entity

My goal is to have this attribute as Select (with data from another db table), but i didn't find any tuto about the source/model that i should create !!

Here is the Files :

**InstallData** `Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Field',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Test,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Source Model (Needed Code) : `Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Test`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;


class Test extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{

    public function __construct(..........) 
{
        ......................
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        ...................

        return $this->_options;
    }


}
```

Could any one help me how to create this source model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install Data**

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Field',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true, 
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'source' => Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Test,
            'system' => 0,

        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'testfield')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**Source Model**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

class Test extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $helper = $obj->create('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
        $tags = $helper->getCollection();
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $label = $tag->getTitle();
            $value = $tag->getTagsId();
            $option[] = array('label'=>$label,'value'=>$value);
        }
        $this->_options = $option;

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

**Helper** `Data.php`

```
protected $_tagsCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Tags\CollectionFactory $tagsCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->_tagsCollectionFactory = $tagsCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_tagsCollectionFactory->create();
    return $collection;
}
```

**Note:** Tags is for example. You can load your collection and return to `getAllOptions` function.

If your install data script successfully installed your custom attribute, now you just need to override addition information phtml file and set your custom attribute in that.

Create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_info_customer" template="Vendor_Module::attribute.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/attribute.phtml`

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Test Field') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="testfield" id="testfield" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test Field') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think my goal wasn't clear. i want to add select attribute to customer with options (label & value) from a database table

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it out. Let me know if you have any confusion or issue

Comment: I get the option in the select for customer form but i have 2 problems : 1- After saving i can't find the value in customer_entity_varchar table. 2- I can't find the field in registration form (in mag1 it appears)

Comment: I still  have no solution. Could you helps to resolve this prb

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: First i wasn't able to save but after adding system => 0 parameter it works.
But the new attribute didn't appear in registration form  (in mag1 it appears)

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I already tried this, but i want a select item in registration form and i don't know how can i get source model options in this <select>